# Widows Server 2016 IIS server install PHP

Tags: php, iis

I try install PHP for Windows Server 2016.

Install from insctruction: https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

I download this menager and find PHP. Install PHP 7.
Error Log: http://ideone.com/gON7Y0

This is new install server, because after I didnt install PHP from my server.
Help ? How install this PHP on the server. Maybe Windows Server 2016 not supported PHP, or bug MS Server.

Answer (score 1):

The error is this:

'This setup requires the .NET Framework version 2.0.  Please install the .NET 
 Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from 
 the web.  Would you like to do this now?'.

So the .NET 2.0 version lies inside the Features of the server (.net version 3.5, contains .net 2.0 and 3.0).
in Server Manager go to, Add roles and features, then next until you find the features, and in there select the ".NEt framework 3.5" .

Wait for the install to finish.
[image: .NET Framework 2.0 location on ws2012r2]

(if you're on-premises you would need the Windows server 2012 ISO and to do this http://www.askvg.com/how-to-install-microsoft-net-framework-3-5-offline-in-windows-8-without-internet-connection/ or

Or in a command prompt with elevated privileges run:

```
DISM  /Online  /Enable-Feature  /FeatureName:NetFx3  /All  /LimitAccess  /Source:x:\sources\sxs
```

After the 3.5 installation run the install again and you shouldn't get any more issues.

Answer (score -2):

follow this guy tutorial it has worked forme today https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuJuhdZo9tU

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.